# Random Uniform Numbers WITHOUT runif()

Tags: r, random

Usually to generate a sequence of uniform random numbers, I use the "runif()" command in R:

```
runif(10,0,10)

 [1] 5.032995 8.712604 4.400579 3.874882 2.401324 2.465861 2.59525 8.570266 2.729831 5.176705
```

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there might be some other way to generate random uniform numbers WITHOUT using the "runif" command. I have heard that random numbers can be generated using the computer's clock, but I am not sure how this is done.

- Is it possible to write an R script that generates random uniform numbers (between some range) such that the "runif" command is not used?

Thank you!

@ Dmitry's Answer in a Loop:

```
v = rep(0,100)
v[1]=3
for (j in 1:100) {
v[j+1]=(65539*v[j])%%(2^31)
}

    i = 1:101

range01 <- function(x, ...){(x - min(x, ...)) / (max(x, ...) - min(x, ...))}
      
    rand_data = data.frame(i,v)
    rand_data$int_version = range01(rand_data$v)


plot(rand_data$v, type = "b", main = "100 Random Real Numbers with Randu")

plot(rand_data$int_version, type = "b", main = "100 Random Integers with Randu")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe this Wikipedia page is a good starting point to learn about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could acquire the fractional seconds from Sys.time and use it as a poor-man's hack for a single draw:

```
as.numeric( substr( as.character( unclass(Sys.time())), start=11,stop=16))
```

It's not going to be a particularly good method of generating a sequence of random numbers.

Comment: @ IRTFM : Thank you for your answer! I posted another question related to your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418723/making-a-list-of-random-numbers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, you'd have to implement one of the [pseudo-random number generation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pseudorandom_number_generators) yourself.  Start with [RANDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU), but never use it for practical purposes, ha-ha

Comment: @ Dmitry: Thank you for your answer! I tried to implement a "loop" using your idea - can you please check to see if I implemented it correctly? Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't ask me -- ask [Kolmogorov and his pal Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) to check whether the data you obtain is distributed differently than U(0,1) :) (`ks.test` in R)

Comment: Also might be interesting to compare with the solution by @IRTFM

Comment: @DmitryZotikov, I would feel more comfortable if your answer included this quotation from Wikipedia: "[RANDU is] widely considered to be **one of the most ill-conceived random number generators ever designed**" and pointed in addition (or instead) to the [Wichmann-Hill generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichmann%E2%80%93Hill); I'm afraid that inexperienced readers may not pick up on the note of irony/warning here ...

Comment: I am sorry for making you feel not comfortable enough, Ben

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am trying to understand why there are flaws with the RANDU algorithm 0- can someone please help me understand this? Thank you!