# Making a List of Random Numbers

Tags: r, random

In another question ([Random Uniform Numbers WITHOUT runif()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418364/random-uniform-numbers-without-runif)), I learned how to generate random numbers using the computer's clock:

```
> as.numeric( substr( as.character( unclass(Sys.time())), start=11,stop=16))
[1] 0.05981
> 
> as.numeric( substr( as.character( unclass(Sys.time())), start=11,stop=16))
[1] 0.00045
> 
> as.numeric( substr( as.character( unclass(Sys.time())), start=11,stop=16))
[1] 0.47185
> 
> as.numeric( substr( as.character( unclass(Sys.time())), start=11,stop=16))
[1] 0.66722
```

The problem is, when I tried to generate 100 of these random numbers at the same time using the above technique:

```
results <- list()

for (i in 1:100) {

    iteration = i

v_i = as.numeric( substr( as.character( unclass(Sys.time())), start=11,stop=16))
 
    results_tmp = data.frame(iteration, v_i)

    results[[i]] <- results_tmp
}

results_df_1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
```

These numbers do not "look" random - they look like they are "ordered":

```
  iteration     v_i
1         1 0.76919
2         2 0.76919
3         3 0.76919
4         4 0.76919
5         5 0.78490
6         6 0.78641
```

We can see this by making a plot:

```
plot(results_df_1$v_i, type = "b", main = "100 Random Numbers Using the Computer's Clock")
```

[image]

- Can someone please explain this: Why do the individually generated numbers "look more random" compared to the "jointly generated numbers"? Is there a way to fix this so that the 100 random numbers look more random?

Thank you!

Comment: Because you're just looking at the clock. That's literally all you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

In my earlier answer I said it was “a poor-man's hack” for a single draw. I expected exactly this sort of non-random result if it were done repeatedly in a machine generated loop. The fix: First run this loop with a Sys.sleep(.) operation that "sleeps" for the number of second specified by the last pseudo random number and then if you ran `sample` on a set of such numbers you might achieve something like you were interested in.